# Oracle glassfish4.1 jms database store

Tags: java, mysql, glassfish, jms

I want to store all my JMS messages to database(for testing how it works). I am using mysql 5.x as database and glassfish 4.1 as application server .
I have made the following changes to default.properties for JMS

1. `imq.persist.store=jdbc`
2. `imq.brokerid=broker1`
3. `imq.persist.jdbc.dbVendor=mysql`
4. `imq.persist.jdbc.mysql.user=root`
5. `imq.persist.jdbc.mysql.password = password`
6. `imq.persist.jdbc.mysql.property.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jms`

I hace copied mysql connector to **ext folder** .
Now when I run ***imqdbmgr create all*** .the following error occurs:

```
    [#|2016-06-20T13:36:44.473+0530|SEVERE|5.1.1|imq.log.Logger|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;|ERROR [B3073]: Failed to create database table(s) - null:
com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsserver.util.BrokerException: [B3073]: Failed to create database table(s) - null
        at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsserver.persist.jdbc.DBTool.doCreate(DBTool.java:252)
        at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsserver.persist.jdbc.DBTool.doCreate(DBTool.java:194)
        at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsserver.persist.jdbc.DBTool.doCommand(DBTool.java:2435)
        at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsserver.persist.jdbc.DBTool.main(DBTool.java:2506)
Caused by: com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsserver.util.BrokerException: [B3025]: No database url specified by imq.persist.jdbc.mysql.createdburl
        at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsserver.persist.jdbc.comm.CommDBManager.connectToCreate(CommDBManager.java:726)
```

What is wrong here . This all works in **Glassfish 3.1** . What is problem with glassfish4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specified :

**`imq.persist.jdbc.mysql.createdburl= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jms`**

and worked.